# iTunes on PlayOnLinux doesn't appear in search

Tags: playonlinux, itunes

I can't find the iTunes on PlayOnLinux search, it just doesn't appear.

Is there other way I could install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ITunes is one of those pieces of software which does not run in Linux.  You could try to use PoL (although you have already discovered it does not work) or you could try Wine, although it is also not supported there.

The only workable solution that I found was to run Windows in a virtual machine, and run ITunes there.  My experience with VirtualBox was that ITunes will run in WinXP and Win7, but not fully in Win8.  VMWare Player is able to support ITunes in Win8, mostly, but I have some problems with older Ipods in Win8/VMWare, and generally stick to Win7/VMWare at this time.

It you decide to use VirtualBox, you will need to capture the USB connection of the IPad/Pod/Phone device using the USB filter capability of VirtualBox.  It takes a little playing around, but can be done.